# Magento2 installtion stuck at 51%

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, magento2

I am installing Magento2 using Xampp in windows 10. I have changed max_execution_time memory_limit but it is stucked at 51% everytime.

[image]

Comment: what is the value of - max_execution_time  ? and memory_limit which you have set ?

Comment: Hey, I have uninstall it and install it without any error till admin logging. The error shows " could not open input file: bin/magento " when trying to fox login error " you did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily is disabled".

Comment: Yes its because of your password is incorrect , please check your password or reset it for the same

Comment: No, I am inserting correct Username and Password.

Answer (score 0):

If You are installing magento with sample data then try magento2 latest version without sample data and after successful installation you can upload sample data by

```
php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to replace few functions and enable some extensions in your php.ini file.You can try couple of things in Gd2.php and Validator.php.
All function and commands are mentioned [here](https://webarchers.com/installing-magento-2-on-xampp-got-stuck-at-51/)